# Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference Xamarin LockScreen

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

I'm attempting to get media lock screen controls working my xamarin android application. It's been a pain getting through and running into another error that I am running out of ideas on how to get through. I am getting this error just before I try to build the notification/lockscreen.

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

There are some other posts out there with people running into the same error but their answers have not solved my situation. I've learned that getting this error probably means that my 'Context' in that line of code is null. I've tried solutions from these different posts [android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44385528/android-content-context-getsystemservicejava-lang-string-on-a-null-object-ref) , [error:Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068530/errorattempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-java-lang-object-android-content-context) , [Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30416991/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-java-lang-object-android-content-context-getsy?rq=1) , and I've tried wrapping the lines in if statements checking to see if Context is null and I'm sure I tried a few other things but nothing has worked out so far.

```
public void Init(DabPlayer Player, bool IntegrateWithLockScreen)
        {
            dabplayer = Player;
            var mSession = new MediaSessionCompat(Application.Context, "MusicService");
            mSession.SetFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FlagHandlesMediaButtons | MediaSessionCompat.FlagHandlesTransportControls);
            var controller = mSession.Controller;
            var description = GlobalResources.playerPodcast;

            if (IntegrateWithLockScreen)
            {
                /* SET UP LOCK SCREEN */
                CreateNotificationChannel();

                dabplayer.EpisodeDataChanged += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    buildNotification(); //comment out to show play button
                    //Set up an intent so that tapping the notifications returns to this app:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity));
                    Intent playPauseIntent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(SecondActivity));
                    // Create a PendingIntent; 
                    const int pendingIntentId = 0;
                    const int firstPendingIntentId = 1;
                    PendingIntent firstPendingIntent =
                        PendingIntent.GetActivity(Application.Context, firstPendingIntentId, intent, 0);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                        PendingIntent.GetActivity(Application.Context, pendingIntentId, playPauseIntent, 0);

                    // Build the notification:
                    var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Application.Context, CHANNEL_ID)
                                  .SetStyle(new Android.Support.V4.Media.App.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                                            .SetMediaSession(mSession.SessionToken)
                                            .SetShowActionsInCompactView(0))
                                  .SetVisibility(NotificationCompat.VisibilityPublic)
                                  .SetContentIntent(firstPendingIntent) // Start up this activity when the user clicks the intent.
                                  .SetDeleteIntent(MediaButtonReceiver.BuildMediaButtonPendingIntent(Application.Context, PlaybackState.ActionStop))
                                  .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.app_icon) // This is the icon to display
                                  .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.ic_media_play_pause, "Play", pendingIntent)
                                  .SetContentText(GlobalResources.playerPodcast.EpisodeTitle)
                                  .SetContentTitle(GlobalResources.playerPodcast.ChannelTitle);

                    // Finally, publish the notification:
                    var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(Application.Context);
                    notificationManager.Notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.Build());
                };

                dabplayer.EpisodeProgressChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
                {

                };
            }
        }
```

Error line is towards bottom of this snippet

```
public void buildNotification()
        {
            Notification.MediaStyle style = new Notification.MediaStyle();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(DroidDabNativePlayer));  //Maybe typeof() is wrong class / Did have lines 131 - 133 in MainActivity
            intent.SetAction(ACTION_STOP);
            //StartService(intent);  //Didn't have this line in there when you and I were looking at it but still throwing same error just at this line
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetService(Application.Context, 1, intent, 0);
            var builder = new Notification.Builder(Application.Context, CHANNEL_ID)
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.app_icon)
                .SetContentTitle("Lock Screen Example")
                .SetContentText("Artist Name")
                .SetDeleteIntent(pendingIntent)
                .SetStyle(style);
            Notification.Action action = new Notification.Action(1, "title", pendingIntent); //fake action for now
            builder.AddAction(generateAction(Resource.Drawable.ic_media_play_dark, "Previous", ACTION_PREVIOUS));
            builder.AddAction(generateAction(Resource.Drawable.ic_media_play_dark, "Rewind", ACTION_REWIND));
            builder.AddAction(action);
            builder.AddAction(generateAction(Resource.Drawable.ic_media_play_dark, "Fast Forward", ACTION_FAST_FORWARD));
            builder.AddAction(generateAction(Resource.Drawable.ic_media_play_dark, "Next", ACTION_NEXT));
            style.SetShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2, 3, 4);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService); //line where error is being thrown
            notificationManager.Notify(1, builder.Build());
        }
```

The exception is caught below

```
public bool Load(dbEpisodes episode)
        {
            try
            {
                //Stop playing the current episode if needed
                if (IsPlaying)
                {
                    Pause(); //Have to use PAUSE on Android or it will reset current time to 0.
                    //Stop();
                }

                //Load a specific episode (sets text properties as well
                EpisodeTitle = episode.title;
                ChannelTitle = episode.channel_title;


                bool rv = Load(episode.File_name);
                OnEpisodeDataChanged(this, new DabPlayerEventArgs(this));
                return rv;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

The tutorial I was trying to follow can be found here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KNsELLrZ3V0

Thank you in advance!

Comment: which specific line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Towards the bottom. I made a comment. var lockScreenManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);

Comment: are any of the objects involved in that line null?

Comment: When i hit the breakpoint it says the variable lockScreenManager is null but I believe that's just because I have not passed that line yet. But if i step into that line then i hit an exception in my load method. 

Then i have info for NotificationManager, Context, and NotificationService. GetSystemService doesn't have any info pop up but it also does not say null.

GetSystemService isn't an object though.

Comment: where do you define Init method ? in activity or service ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT it's in a service. DroidDabNativePlayer.cs : Service.

I just broke the code up into different methods so it might be easier to see. It's my second notification (lock screen) that is not currently working. The one within BuildNotification(). My context must be null for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the line in my buildNotification() method from

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
```

to

```
 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
```

And that got rid of that error at least. Now I am just getting 2 notifications posted to the users phone when really I am trying to get media controls on the users lock screen but, that's just another topic in general I guess. Thank you everybody.